# why ctypes.addressof() give diifferent result using python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, ctypes, addressof

Recently I'm trying to transfer from python2 to python3,in my codes there is some job about read data form hardware that have a .py interface file call foreign .dll lib. The data is shared by memory between .dll and python routine,specifically speaking, ctypes.creat_string_buffer() and ctypes.addressof(), which run correctly under python2.7 env,but give unexpected result under python3.6, the reason seems to be that ctypes.addressof() give huge difference address value, I wonder what's the reason?

'''python2.7 output of addressof()

```
(base) C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> s = 128
>>> p = create_string_buffer(s)
>>> print(addressof(p))
50341488
>>> hex(addressof(p))
'0x3002670L'
```

'''

'''python3.6 output of addressof()

```
(base) C:\Users\Administrator>conda activate py36

(py36) C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> s = 128
>>> p = create_string_buffer(s)
>>> print(addressof(p))
>>> 2241150277680
>>> hex(addressof(p))
>>> '0x209cef75830'
```

'''

In my opinion,the output of addressof() funtion under python2 and python3 should be approximate,but in fact it's not。Some one who can help me to point what's wrong with the routine,or with me , appreciatively!

Answer (score 0):

[[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

`ctypes.addressof` doesn't have anything to do with the values, it simply reports the address of the underlying *C* buffer for the *ctypes* object.

It's about:

- `ctypes.create_string_buffer` (which returns a `ctypes.c_char` array)
- How *ctypes* allocates objects: *PyCData_MallocBuffer* which in turn calls ***PyMem_Malloc*** (check [[Python 3.Docs]: Memory Management](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#memory-management) for a bit more details)
- *PyMem_Malloc* (in *Release* mode):

  - For *Python 2*, it's a *malloc* wrapper
  - For *Python 3*, things are more complex, allocations occurs in blocks, user contexts are present, ..., but in the end it still relies on *malloc* (or one of its family functions)

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\WINDOWS\system32]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> set _PYTHON2="e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
>
> [prompt]> set _PYTHON3="e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
>
> [prompt]> rem PYTHON 3 - CTYPES
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON3% -c "from ctypes import *; print(hex(addressof(create_string_buffer(128))))"
> 0x25652521230
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON3% -c "from ctypes import *; print(hex(addressof(create_string_buffer(128))))"
> 0x25c61371230
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON3% -c "from ctypes import *; print(hex(addressof(create_string_buffer(128))))"
> 0x20a3dfd1230
>
> [prompt]> rem PYTHON 2 - CTYPES
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON2% -c "from ctypes import *; print(hex(addressof(create_string_buffer(128))))"
> 0x2f5f3b0L
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON2% -c "from ctypes import *; print(hex(addressof(create_string_buffer(128))))"
> 0x262f3b0L
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON2% -c "from ctypes import *; print(hex(addressof(create_string_buffer(128))))"
> 0x313f3b0L
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> rem PYTHON 3 - REGULAR
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON3% -c "print(hex(id(1234567)))"
> 0x1df0d6af5b0
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON3% -c "print(hex(id(1234567)))"
> 0x14f39e7f5b0
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON3% -c "print(hex(id(1234567)))"
> 0x1f61453f5b0
>
> [prompt]> rem PYTHON 2 - REGULAR
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON2% -c "print(hex(id(1234567)))"
> 0x2a2ca90L
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON2% -c "print(hex(id(1234567)))"
> 0x325c6a0L
>
> [prompt]> %_PYTHON2% -c "print(hex(id(1234567)))"
> 0x28bbec0L
> ```

As seen, the memory addresses pattern is not related to *ctypes* objects, but to all (and the address is different every time).

Note that relying on the fact that an address pointing to some memory that has been allocated by *malloc* (or friends) is equal (or close) to some value, is a bad idea. **Code relying on such assumptions, is bad** (might say that's the equivalent of *Undefined Behavior*).